# Какой фреймворк нужен на Linux для разработки приложений windows forms?

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, framework, rider

[image: Скриншот окна для создания нового решения]IDE JetBrains Riders. Установлен mono (mono-complete), sdk core. Собираюсь писать на c#. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каких "target framework" не хватает.

Comment: Windows forms не кросплатформеный. Только под windows можно  запустить

Comment: https://www.mono-project.com/